# Request: Please take time while reviewing close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review

First I must say, the new review system is great. It is easier to review items, especially the linked duplicate question tab is very useful.

But I think, the easiness of reviewing posts has posed good possibility of bad review. I have seen some questions (I'm not willing to give a link here) getting closed too quickly and the close reasons aren't very good. *(honestly, I consider them bad)*

That is why I am posting this meta thread. I hope the situation will be taken into notice.

#### My advice will be

1. Please take your time reviewing posts, especially the close voted posts. The votes can be wrong. ***Please don't give a close vote to a question just because someone started it***. The review should be a review by 5 individual users. If I am not sure, I'll be clicking on "Not sure" button.
2. While reviewing the duplicate question posts, read all the duplicate questions. If possible reading the answer will be very good.

Comment: I'd like to add that I will frequently cast a close vote for a reason **different from the suggestion offered**, however the question is closed and then it looks as if I have agreed with the majority on the reason. For example, I close-voted [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/198818/12864) as 'Not a real question'(too broad) and yet I'm  listed as one of five who decided it was a dupe. It isn't, it's too broad. Excellent request though. We've incentivized the review process, with progress bars, etc. It's very easy to want to just go through very quickly, like playing a game for a high score.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. and there are *badges* for review numbers.. It is tempting sometimes

Comment: I agree, I see posts closed because they "may be better elsewhere" or even closed as off-topic even when the FAQ specifically says otherwise.

Comment: @TomBrossman same here even I voted that for `Not a real question` but it is shown as "closed as exact duplicate".

Comment: @devav2 This is happening because a question just need 5 close votes. And the catagory of majority of voters is selected as the closing reason of the question. So, even if you voted the question for `Not a real question`, it can be closed as `exact duplicate` if majority (say 3) voters voted it as such

Answer (score 8):

At present when we decide to *"Do not close"* a question this is relevant to our own review queue only. It will not (and should not) neutralize close votes cast by others. But it is not displayed anywhere.

We need to comment our disagreement (or vote on a disagreeing comment if there) in the hope people read it before casting their votes.

It would be a nice and helpful feature to have the number of *"Do not close"* votes cast by others listed. Can this easily be made possible?

Comment: +1 for the feature. But the problem is many times those comments are ignored by close voters. that is the point of this post. I think, some do not spend enough time to read the comments. (sad)